# Simple javascript condition

Tags: javascript

What I want to achieve is if the time frame between d1 and d2 matches with our system time the "#timer" should display after clicking the "try out" button which will trigger the "myFunction". In all other cases the "#timer" should not be visible on page load. Now the "#timer" is visible even before clicking on the tryout button. And now the time is not matching with the system time, still it displays. I don't know where I'm wrong. Would appreciate those who can help me out.

```js
function myFunction() { 
 
var currentdate = new Date();
var d1 = new Date("2021-05-18 03:32:00");
var d2 = new Date("2021-05-18 03:33:00");


if ((currentdate >= d1) && (currentdate <= d2)) {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("timer").style.display = "none";
}
};
```

```css
#timer{
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background:#ff934f;
            
            }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: `myFunction()` only runs once you hit the button.  When the page loads, there is nothing that hides `#timer`.  Try adding `display: none;` to the CSS for `#timer`.

Comment: The `#timer` doesn't appear to be hidden by default.

Comment: Also, just FYI `03:32:00`, is 3:32 am.  To help debug the time comparisons, try `console.log(currentdate.toString());`.

Answer (score 0):

## watch the clock with setInterval

You want a button that is disabled most of the time, but becomes enabled during a narrow window of time.

*First, a warning: **do not rely on this for security**; it will be trivial for hackers to defeat this. However, it's fine for a toy app, or if all your users can be trusted to play by the rules.*

All you need is javascript. The HTML & CSS don't matter, except for identifying which element to disable/enable.

```js
let MY_BUTTON = document.getElementById('timer')
let START_DATE = new Date( /* TBD */ )
let END_DATE = new Date( /* TBD */ )

/*
    Watch the clock / like a hawk
*/
setInterval(
    () => timelockElement(MY_BUTTON, START_DATE, END_DATE),
    250 // see note
)

/*
    Keep an element disabled unless the current time is between two dates
*/
function timelockElement( element, activateAt, deactivateAt ) {
    // check enablement window
    let now = new Date()
    let elementShouldBeEnabled = dateIsBetween(now, activateAt, deactivateAt)
    
    // apply current verdict to page
    element.setAttribute('disabled', !elementShouldBeEnabled)
}

/*
    Does date A fall between dates B & C?
*/
function dateIsBetween( myDate, d1, d2 ) {
    // put all three dates in order
    let ordered = [ myDate, d1, d2 ].sort()
    
    // myDate falls between them IFF it's the one in the middle
    return ordered[1] === myDate
}
```

Hopefully that's not too hard to follow:

- several times per second, compare the current timestamp to fixed start- and end-timestamps
- update the `enabled` attribute on `#timer` to reflect the result of that comparison

A couple noteworthy choices I made:

- `250` will check the clock ~4 times per second. The best value for you will depend on how real-time you want the update to be, which decision is itself sensitive to the window length and how likely your users are to be watching the clock themselves. E.g.: people buying tickets online want you to use an atomic clock and update in [Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_time_and_length); people waiting to poke their tamagochi can probably check twice every three seconds.
- This technique for checking the date autocorrects for putting your start and end times backwards. I think that's reasonable, but if you need to build an app that will blindly honor bad configuration, you *will* have to change the implementation of `dateIsBetween`. It also doesn't include the window endpoints, which will only matter if by some miracle one user's timer fires at the exact millisecond of the start or end times.
- I used `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. Very often, `setTimeout` is the best tool for time-repeating behavior *even when* the behavior must repeat indefinitely, because `setTimeout`'s reliance on tail-recursion helps you avoid overlapping hearbeats when the heartbeat function is long-running. That is hugely important. I didn't bother in this case because the workload is trivial.

And, as others have noted, you are probably configuring your testing dates wrongly (unless you really are working on this at 3am GMT).